# How do you psuedocode this problem? How do simplify this problem before writing the code?

Tags: pseudocode

> Your week is almost always the same. On the list of things to do for the day, you brush your teeth, take a shower, eat breakfast, drive your car to work, work/field work/meetings, come home, eat dinner at home, sleep. There are some days where your activities change.
>
> 1. On Wednesdays, you don’t eat breakfast as you need to be really early for work.
> 2. Monday, Wednesday and Friday, you have office work, while you have meetings on Tuesday, and field work on Thursday.
> 3. On Tuesdays, you take the bus instead of driving since your car is coding on that day.
> 4. On Fridays, you eat dinner out with your family and watch a movie.
>
> Create pseudocode that shows your week detailed activities. TAKE NOTE that you can only use one loop.

I have researched about adding and removing in arrays.
Looked into nested loops but it requires just 1 loop

```
var week = [monday ,tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday]

var toDo = [Brush teeth ,take shower ,eat breakfast ,drive car ,work ,come home ,eat dinner at home]

for (day in week) {

    var monday += toDo;
}

return monday
```

Just wanted your version on how you will approach / pseudocode this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since *you can only use one loop*, a second array (toDo) isn't of use, since a second loop would be needed to process that. A possible approach is:

```
var week = [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday]
for day in week
{
    brush teeth
    take shower
    if day is not Wednesday, eat breakfast
    if day is Tuesday, take bus, else drive car to work
    if day is Monday, Wednesday or Friday, office work
    else if day is Tuesday, meetings
    else (day is Thursday) field work
    come home
    if day is Friday, eat dinner out and watch movie, else eat dinner at home
    sleep
}
```